# HTML page reload on condition using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I need the HTML page to be reloaded if a value in a certain input field (pass_phrase) was not changed after a certain time, like 2 min, let us say. I am new to JS and the below code is what I came with so far. But it does not work. If I enter some value, the page never reloads. Please help to point to the right solution or an issue with the code. Thanks.

JS :

```
    var v1 = '', v2 = '';           
    function GetMyValues(){        
        setTimeout(function() {
            v1 = document.getElementById('pass_phrase').value;
        }, 1000*60*1);        
        setTimeout(function() {
            v2 = document.getElementById('pass_phrase').value;
        }, 1000*60*2);        
    }  

    if (v1 == v2 && v1 != '') {
       window.location="https://domain-name.com";
    } else {
       setTimeout('GetMyValues()', 1000*60*1);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are only checking `v1` and `v2` on page load. You need to check it when you need it (after the timeout):

```
var v1 = '', v2 = '';

function GetMyValues() {

    setTimeout(function () {
        v1 = document.getElementById('pass_phrase').value;
    }, 1000 * 60 * 1);

    setTimeout(function () {
        v2 = document.getElementById('pass_phrase').value;
        // Check and reload
        if (v1 == v2 && v1 != '') {
            window.location = "https://domain-name.com";
            // or location.reload(); if it is really a reload of the same page.
        } 
    }, 1000 * 60 * 2);

}

setTimeout(GetMyValues, 1000 * 60 * 1);
```

Although this checks it after 3 seconds, since you trigger `GetMyValues` after 1 minute and than wait for 2 minutes to compare the 2 values.
If you want to check the values 2 minutes after page load you should change:

```
setTimeout(GetMyValues, 1000 * 60 * 1);
```

to just:

```
getMyValues();
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use this instead to reload your page:

```
location.reload();
```

Look at [this](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_loc_reload.asp) documentation.

Comment: If you call `location.reload(true)` then it will tell the browser to skip cache and grab a fresh copy of the page.